# Creating an UPDATE trigger that causes the removal of the triggering row

Tags: oracle

I'm on Oracle Express 11g. I'm trying to create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_useless_surveys 
     BEFORE UPDATE OF agent_id, agency_id, province_id ON surveys 
     FOR EACH ROW WHEN (
     new.agent_id IS NULL AND 
     new.agency_id IS NULL AND
     new.province_id IS NULL)
DELETE FROM surveys WHERE survey_code = :new.survey_code
```

agent_id, agency_id and province_id are foreign keys, with ON DELETE SET NULL clause.

I need a row in the surveys table to be DELETED when all the three foreign keys are set to NULL (because the referred rows are deleted).

The trigger compiles with no problems, but when the condition fires, then I get this error:

> SQL error: ORA-04091: table REALESTATE.SURVEYS is mutating,
>   trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at
>   "REALESTATE.REMOVE_USELESS_SURVEYS", line 1 ORA-04088: error during
>   execution of trigger 'REALESTATE.REMOVE_USELESS_SURVEYS'
>   04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
>   *Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>              this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>              in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Actually, I know I'm editing the same table that fired the trigger. But I want to cancel the update, or finalize it, I don't care, and then **delete that row**.

Can you help me? How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: May be the statement executed a trigger or PL/SQL function. That trigger/function tried to modify or query a table that is currently being modified by the statement that fired the trigger/function.Pls check the http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora04091.php

Comment: @user1127214: yeah, this is the point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a statement level trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_useless_surveys 
AFTER UPDATE OF agent_id, agency_id, province_id ON surveys 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM surveys 
  WHERE  agent_id IS NULL 
  AND    agency_id IS NULL
  AND    province_id IS NULL;
END;
```

Comment: +1. However, if the table is large this might add a signficant performance problem to every update on the table... which might be mitigated by a suitable function-based index.